# Bashscript for editing .vcf files

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, gnome-terminal

I am trying to write a bash script for editing my mobile contacts.(.vcf file). my contacts numbers started with "0046", "+46" , "013", "093". The first two are the prefix of the country number, and the second two are the starting number without the prefix (+46).
I want to import contacts to a bash script and make some change in my contacts numbers. I want to use **"if statements"**.

- **If** the numbers started with **0046**,  they will change to **+46**.
- **If** the numbers started with **013**, they will change to **+4613**

And then, save the new file in current directory.

**a sample of a vc file:**

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:;Name;;;
FN:Name
TEL;CELL;PREF:0046 133 493 ****
END:VCARD
```

i want to use simple solutions:

```
1- cat my_contacts.vcf
2- sed "s/+46/0046/g" > new_edited_contacts.vcf
3- etc...
```

i have another problem with writing bashs:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd home/username/Desktop/
cnvalues= $(cat contacts.vcf)
echo "$cnvalues"
sed -i -e "s/PREF:0098/PREF:+98/g" -e "s/PREF:09/PREF:+989/g" $cnvalues
```

when i use above code, in terminal i see this messages(No such file or directory):

```
Bash_contact.sh: line 2: cd: $'home/username/Desktop/\r': No such file or directory
Bash_contact.sh: line 3: cat: No such file or directory
Bash_contact.sh: line 3: $'\r': command not found
```

Comment: Show us what you have done and where you are stuck?

Comment: We'll need to know the format of the .vcf file to get an idea of what solutions might be suitable. Can you edit your question with a sample of text from the .vcf file? I'd probably recommend `sed` to make these sorts of changes.

Comment: Bash script is probably not the best choice for parsing and modifying vCard files.

Comment: thank you, i edited my post. please see that.

Comment: Your `sed` command is the wrong way around. Your first entry (between the /'s) should be the string you're looking for/replacing. The second entry should be the new value, so you'd want `sed "s/0046/+46/g"`, but this will replace all occurrences of 0046

Comment: yes i know, no matter. Because I only have numbers with this prefix. but I had two conditions, how i can write both of them with using of "if".

Comment: Just do it in two separate sed strings, or use this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/97437

Comment: how i should write in if statement , if [........] then sed ....

Comment: There shouldn't be any need for an if statement, as if `sed` doesn't find the "0046" string, it won't do anything. Same for if the "013" string doesn't exist, so it effectively has a built-in "if".

Comment: But there is a problem with the second condition. can we use "cut" or Similar commands for say to sef If 013 was only at the beginning of the numbers, change it. not the others.(maybe contacts have 013 in another part of thier numbers)

Comment: Then we need to know the condition defining "The start of a number". It's obvious for humans, but a script needs to be told exactly what means the start of a number. How will the numbers always appear in the .vcf file?

Comment: if i want use if statements, Can I use a variable_name for "cat contacts.vcf? and call that in "if statements" with $variable_name ?

Comment: my contacts numbers started with "0046", "+46" , "013", "093". The first two are the prefix of the country number and the second two are the starting number without the prefix (+۴۶)

Comment: This is all useful information to add to your question. However, we still don't have a way of determining when a number starts. In your example, the number is preceded by `PREF:`. Is this always in front of a phone number?

Comment: of course i will add them and thank you to remind. yes it is in front of all phone numbers.

Comment: In that case, use `sed "s/PREF:0046/PREF:+46/g"` and `sed "s/PREF:013/PREF:+4613/g"` and you're only then replacing the starts of phone numbers!